# How to get user input with string prompt?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get a user's input with a prompt, how can I do that in ruby?

If I've explained poorly what my problem is, here is an example written in python of what I would like to do: `Input("Prompt: ")`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puts "Prompt: "
var = gets
```

'gets' is used to take input from the user and it returns a string of text by default. But the new line character will be added. Like your input is 'Akshit' then '\n' will be added to the string 'Akshit\n'.So to remove that you can use 'chomp'.

```
puts "Prompt: "
var = gets.chomp
```

In case you want to take integer input you can do something like this,

```
puts "Prompt: "
var = gets.chomp.to_i
```

'to_i' will convert the string to an integer.
There are other methods like to_f(to float),to_a(to array),to_c(to character) etc...